# Why does this does not refer to an current variable in this code

Tags: javascript, reference, this

```js
var colors = [
    "rgb(25, 105 ,34)",
    "rgb(55, 165 ,94)",
    "rgb(20, 19,35)",
    "rgb(2, 10 ,3)",
    "rgb(09, 10 ,34)",
    "rgb(5, 10 ,34)"
];

var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
    This.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

`This` keyword in for loop should directly refer to our square object but is shows an error of undefined object what's the reason behind it on changing it to `square[i]` is works fine

Comment: If the number of items with `square` class in your HTML is greater than the number of `colors` items you will get `undefined` for a color. Can you share more of your code? What would `this` refer to?

Comment: ```this``` keyword in ```for``` loop not  refer to square its refer to window object scoop or higher function scoop ,.. where your code has been written  , try ```console.log(this)``` to see where refer to

Answer (score 0):

`this` should be lower case and in this case, `this` does not refer to items of `square`

> By default, the execution context for an execution is global — which
> means if a code is being executed as part of a simple function call,
> then `this` refers to a global object.
>
> The `window` object is the global
> object in the case of the browser. And in a NodeJS environment, a
> special object called `global` will be the value of this.

https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8

You need to access items by using `square[i]`

**Update**

As stated in the comments by @VLAZ, in order not to get `undefined` error, you can use `modulo` operator to get color from the array

```js
var colors = [
    "rgb(25, 105 ,34)",
    "rgb(55, 165 ,94)",
    "rgb(20, 19,35)",
    "rgb(2, 10 ,3)",
    "rgb(09, 10 ,34)",
    "rgb(5, 10 ,34)"
];
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i % colors.length]
    //                                   ^^^^^^^
}
```

```css
.square{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```